# Starting Rails app on Windows with latest version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

Trying to start an app developed on Mac and hosted on Github, now trying to start that application on Windows Vista.

Ruby Version: 1.9.2-p136
Installed Dev Kit
Installed MySQL Gem
Gem Version: 1.5.2
Also did 'bundle install'

Getting the following

```
$ rails server
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 1
83 column 9 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.3/lib/redcloth/for
matters/latex.rb:6:in `<module:LATEX>'
```

Researching for the error message on google, found the following http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4301

Please help in starting this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your Rails application is trying to open and parse a YAML file, which is normally used for configuration.

A parsing error could be generated due an incorrect encoding inside one of these files.

Reading RedCloth [source code that triggers this](https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/RELEASE_4_2_3/lib/redcloth/formatters/latex.rb#L6) seems that [latex_entities.yml](https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/RELEASE_4_2_3/lib/redcloth/formatters/latex_entities.yml) is the culprit.

What you can try to do is update to latest version of RedCloth (4.2.3 seems a bit old) and 4.2.7 is the latest one.

You can also try downloading the above mentioned file and using a IRB console:

```
require 'psych'
require 'yaml'
YAML.load_file "latex_entities.yml"
```

Above works for latest (4.2.7) but not with 4.2.3

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is built with rails 1.x to rails 2.x is better you use InstantRails which can be downloaded from [rubyforge.org](https://rubyforge.org/projects/instantrails/). But if it is built with rails 3.x i advice you use [rails installer](https://rubyforge.org/projects/railsinstaller/). This are the two best platforms that can make any open source application run on windows. Hope this helps you

Comment: [Here is the latest new Rails Installer "Main Site"](http://www.railsinstaller.org/)